# How to reset DEFAULT value on a column On ORACLE TABLE

Tags: sql, oracle, default, ddl

I have a table in which one of the column is set default to 0000 and the data type of of the column is number.
I want to remove the default value and when a record is saved null should save on this column.

Answer (score 5):

You could override default to `NULL`:

```
ALTER TABLE tab_name MODIFY col_name DEFAULT NULL;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=edbd2235024982267e598e903b98daf6)**

---

If columns was set as `NOT NULL` then:

```
ALTER TABLE tab_name MODIFY col_name type_name DEFAULT NULL NULL;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4a9e7b7435bc8029de0f213c1987bc8e)**

Comment: @OP Also, if you want it to be consistent consider a one-off update to make the current 0 records null.

Comment: @Error_2646 Yes, I agree but it depends on requirements.

Answer (score 0):

First, update current records:

```
update tab set col=null where col=0;
```

Then remove default value:

```
alter tab modify col default null;
```